# How to see request headers and parameters in react native

Tags: react-native

New to `react Native`. Just like we can see all the `API calls` and the `headers`, as well as the `request & response parameters`, passed to the APIs from the network tab from the browsers, similarly, is there any way we can see the same while developing `mobile applications` in react native?

Comment: you could configure a reverse proxy to MITM your android/ios emulator. Something like https://mitmproxy.org/ would work

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flipper if you use `React-Native v0.62+`. Flipper has a very neat network inspector and It has also plenty of debugging utilities.

> Use the Network inspector to inspect outgoing network traffic in your apps. You can easily browse all requests being made and their responses. The plugin also supports gzipped responses.

According to Flipper's official documentation.

Here is an example screenshot from the Flipper Network tab:

[image: flipper network plugin]

There are some other network inspectors but I highly recommend using Flipper.